# window.open object change parent element?

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm not the most javascript savy. I've seen posts for children windows getting parent values but not vice versa.

Basically, I want to invoke a window object with window.open. After some user input is entered in the new window, I want to stuff that input into the original window that invoked the window.open.

The only ways I can think to do this are messy. I don't need any code examples. But if it is possible and you can example it to me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a new window, [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.opener) contains a reference to the parent window (i.e. the window that opened this window).

Comment: Okay, so I can just go up the DOM chain by using parent.whatever?

Comment: In your child window, `window.opener` will refer to the parent window. From there, you can go wherever you want.